# How do I show the last 10 rows in the table?

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
private static IEnumerable<string> getExtrato(string query)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAD-PC-023\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bank;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = query })
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var result = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read() == true && result.Count <= 9 )
            {
                if (reader.GetString(1) == "0")
                {   //+ "ficando assim com: " + reader.GetDecimal(3)
                    result.Add("\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " levantou: " + reader.GetString(2) + " euros, "  + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add("\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " depositou: " + reader.GetString(1) + " euros, " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<string> extratoOperacao(string numeroCartao)
{
    return getExtrato($@"SELECT CardNumber, Deposit, Withdraw, DataHora FROM MoveInfo WHERE CardNumber = '{numeroCartao}'");
}
```

As I have is presenting me only the first 10 lines, but I need the last 10 by normal order, how do I do that?
If anyone can help me, I'd be grateful

Comment: Show the whole method code please.

Comment: At a guess, it's reading from a database, in which case you could reverse the `ORDER BY [columnName]` in the query by using `ORDER BY [columnName] DESC`.

Comment: yes it's reading from a database, so will show the last lines but on the contrary right ? I want this to show in the correct order but only the last 10 @AndrewMorton

Comment: If you make a query without an ORDER BY, the database is free to return the rows in any order it wants to, and it does not have to return them in the same order each time either. What order do you want the records in?

Comment: @AndrewMorton by id order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> getExtrato(string query)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAD-PC-023\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bank;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = query })
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var result = new List<string>();

            // Let's remove unused conditions
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetString(1) == "0")
                {
                    result.Add("\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " levantou: " + reader.GetString(2) + " euros, "  + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add("\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " depositou: " + reader.GetString(1) + " euros, " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3));
                }
            }

            // HERE IS THE MAGIC
            return result.TakeLast(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's working perfectly, you're a living god :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql) in the query you can make sure which records are returned, and you can use [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql) to restrict the quantity of records returned, so something like

```
return getExtrato($@"SELECT TOP 10 [CardNumber], [Deposit], [Withdraw], [DataHora], [Id] FROM [MoveInfo] WHERE [CardNumber] = '{numeroCartao}' ORDER BY [Id] DESC");
```

will return the desired records, and then you just need to read *all* of them and reverse the result in your code (there are other possibilities, but that might be simplest for now).

Comment: I tested this one now and it's better to run with a lot of data, thanks :)